# SO Careers, pdf view of CV: showing our SO rep

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, cv

Under the ***Projects & Interest*** section--as it appears in the pdf view of my SO Careers Profile--is the url for my SO user page, and below that:

> Written 328 answers. Active in python, r, numpy, machine learning and
>   4 other tags.

I have learned that employers are becoming more knowledgeable about SO every day, so *would listing our **rep** alongside "Written 328 answers" be useful?*

Second (and this is so closely related that i thought a single post is best) the template you've chose for the pdf view is really nice (my prior CVs look like handwritten Post-it notes, by comparison) and i think a naked url is out of place. Is making that url an ***active link*** in the pdf document (i.e., just showing the anchor text) something worth consideration.

So for instance,

*how it looks now:*

**Projects And Interests:**      **Stack Overflow**--https://stackoverflow.com/users/66549/doug

*proposed revision:*

**Projects And Interests**:  [My StackOverflow Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66549/doug)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have implemented the solution in @PaulRichardOldridge's answer for hot linking the urls, and additionally I added the feature to open source project links.

When it comes to exposing site reputation to employers, there are at least a couple of issues.  First, reputation by it's self is almost meaningless.  If the employer has no concept of the range of scores or the average speed at which reputation is gained, then there is nothing to compare the seemingly random number to.  Second, the reputation alone does not portray a user's expertise in any set of technologies which the employer is looking for.  By showing the number of questions answered, we feel we can provide employers with a good estimation of the amount of content the candidate has produced, which they can further explore.

Answer (score 7):

I agree that it should be clickable, but I do not agree with the proposed solution that the url should be removed from the links text. It should be more like:

**Stack Overflow** – https://stackoverflow.com/users/66549/doug

The reason being that the pdf is designed to be printer friendly, and `My StackOverflow Profile` will not be useful to a potential employer who receives your CV by paper.